# HTML background box for block of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Completely new to HTML, I need an html file which does the above:

1. Some background color for the whole page.
2. In the center of the page, a block of text within a box of white background color.
3. Directly under (outside of) the white box, a small line of text at the center of page.

Comment: Have you learned about HTML yet? It's customary to at least attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking for help here.

Comment: stack overflow community for helping developers to solve problems but not to ask them to do your work. try to learn and do it . if you faced any problem then ask.

Comment: Understood, i needed a lot more than what's shown here. And I have done research, not sure what would be the best practice. But thanks for getting me started, will figure the rest out myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do it, but this is my way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color:color here;
            }
            #example-name {
                background-color:white;
            }
            #example-2 {
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='example-name' style="margin: 0 auto">
            example content
        </div>
        <div id='example-2'>
            <p>example text</p>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:tan">
<p style="margin-left: 30%;margin-right: 30%; background-color: white; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
 Hi.<br>
Thanks for using Mailgun! Please confirm your email address by clicking below!<br>
I hope this answers your question!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Use the css elements margin, background-color, and padding.